# how can I change OpenSSH default "nas-identifier"?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, openssh, pam, radius

sorry for my poor English.

I setting up a fully working Radius server for SSH authentication and it work without any problem.

I just want to know: how can I change default ubuntu/openssh "NAS Identifier" which already is: sshd

Thank you in advanced
Regards

I search whole ubuntu with below code but I can't find the file which define default ubuntu/openssh default nas identifier:

grep -R "sshd" /